# Bachelors thesis on my desired topic already written by previous years students

Tags: thesis, bachelor

There really is only one topic that I find interesting, useful and that I have alot of knowledge of. However students of previous years had already chosen this topic and written Bachelors thesis on it.

How bad would it be if at least half of my thesis was already researched in previous years thesis?

Comment: For anyone wondering - I ended up improving on the work the previous students had done with a more practical approach and examples/experiments.

Answer (score 8):

Unlike dissertations, bachelor’s theses need not be on an original topic or advance the frontiers of knowledge (although those goals are desirable!). A bachelor’s thesis is intended to show that the student is capable of synthesizing information to produce a useful result via research in some form or another.

So unless the school has a requirement that topics cannot be repeated, there is no reason why you shouldn’t be able to produce a work on a similar topic. That said, your work should not be identical to the previous work (which you should cite and discuss in your thesis!)

Comment: Doesn't that mean one should not repeat a topic but it's okay to keep working on a topic if the prior results are unsatisfying or leave room for more? I think there's an important difference.

Comment: It might be looking at the problem with a different technique or strategy, or coming up with new evidence or insights. It need not be an actual improvement.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's not a professional way to look at the concept of research. In most of the cases, researchers try to improve upon other related researches (usually conducted by community and their colleagues). This fact actually helps us to have a better understanding about the whole problem, and also the solutions other researchers tried before.

In my opinion you can start reading your colleagues' theses to get to know their research, their novelty and their ideas. After that you are well equipped to start with a new idea to improve the topic your colleagues also worked on previously.

But keep in mind for a bachelor student the most important things are building a good background based on the courses you took and also trying out the standard methods of research (on a topic you are really passionate about) without considering the real novelty or quality. Though it is really nice that you care about such matters.